# Como redireccionar a una página según la respuesta recibida de php en ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como puedo redireccionar a una página de acuerdo a la respuesta recibida en php

```
success: function(datos){
  if(datos=='1'){
    //url 
  }else{
    //url 
  }
}
```

Comment: `window.location.replace(url)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Así podrías redireccionar desde javascript:

```
 success: function(datos){

 if(datos=='1'){
   location.href ="http://www.pagina1.com";
   }
    else {
     location.href="http://www.pagina2.com";
   }
 }
```

Saludos..

Answer (score 5):

En javascript puedes usar la propiedad [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location) para redireccionar a otra página:

```
// funciona como una redirección HTTP
window.location.replace("http://sitioweb.com");

// funciona como si dieras clic en un enlace
window.location.href = "http://sitioweb.com";
```

Comment: cabe aclarar que `replace` no deja la url que lanza la redireccion en el historial a diferencia de asignar el valor de `href` que si queda en el historico. Con replace no puedes hacer back pues iras a la pagina anterior a la que hizo la redireccion.

Comment: Pero `window.location.href` sirve dentro de funciones, también?

Answer (score 4):

Depende de lo que intentes, puedes optar por usar una de estas:

`windows.location.href = 'http://url.com';`: Asignar este valor mantiene la entrada actual en el historico del navegador. Por lo que si apretas el boton back del navegador, volvera a la pagina que hizo la redireccion. Es decir la pagina donde corres el ajax.

`windows.location.replace('http://url.com');`: En cambio este método remplaza la entrada actual del historico por lo que cuando haces back volveras a la url anterior a la pagina que hizo la redireccion.

Dependiendo del caso de uso, se utiliza una o la otra. Es decir que si hacer back, volverá a lanzar la redirección automáticamente, convendría usar `replace` para no bloquear al usuario el botón de back.

Answer (score 1):

Para direccionamiento a una pagina según la respuesta de `AJAX` usa esto :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: {datos:"datos"},
        success: function (data) {
          //data es la respuesta del php
          if(data){
            window.location.replace("http://sitioweb.com");
          }

      }
});
```