# Quiero que cuando complete la compra me redirija a otra pagina, alguien sabe como

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url, redirección

Quiero que cuando el pago este completo lo mande a otra pagina (todo lo hago con php, js y los pagos con Culqi) si mal no recuerdo era algo de

`if(nombredepropiedad.status == 'COMPLETED');`

ósea si el pago estaba completo lo mandaba a otra pagina pero no estoy seguro ;alguien me podría ayudar por favor

```
<script>
    Culqi.publicKey = 'Aquí inserta tu llave pública';
    Culqi.settings({
        title: 'Culqi Store',
        currency: 'PEN',
        description: 'Polo Culqi lover',
        amount: 3500
    });
    $('#buyButton').on('click', function(e) {
        Culqi.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function culqi() {

          if (Culqi.token) {
              var token = Culqi.token.id;
          })
          } else {
              console.log(Culqi.error);
              alert(Culqi.error.user_message);
          }
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Porfavor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Se trata de redirigir a otra página, es una pregunta frecuente que puedes encontrar respondida, por ejemplo en [Como redireccionar una página según la respuesta recibida en un php o en ajax?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18138/221201x). El mecanismo de redirección es el mismo.

Comment: estoy seguro que eso esta en la documentacion, ejemplo en *Mercado Pago* se llaman *back_urls*, deberias buscar